# MODx url rewriting nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, modx-revolution

We have a modx site and we are trying to rewrite URL. but everytime it is failing it has pattern like

www.example.com/abc.html?arg1=x123&arg2=555L

we want to rewrite it like 
www.example.com/hello/x123-555L
how we can do that

We are using nginx server

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com example.com;
root /var/www/test;
index index.php index.html;
location ~* .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf)$ {
expires 30d;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "public";
}

location ~ .(aspx|jsp|cgi)$ {
return 410;
}

# exclude /favicon.ico from logs
location = /favicon.ico {
log_not_found off;
access_log off;
}

if ($host = "example.com") {
rewrite ^ $scheme://www.example.com$uri permanent;
}

location / {
root /var/www/test;
try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
}

#www.example.com/abc.html?arg1=x123&arg2=555L =>  www.example.com/hello/x123-555L
location = /abc-xyz.html {
rewrite ^ /hello/$arg_arg1-$arg_arg2 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME $http_host;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny  all;
}
}
```

Comment: didn't understand clearly, which of these two links you want to see in your browser, and which of them you want to be actually passed to backend

Comment: 2nd url is expected  url

Answer (score 0):

Sorry still don't understand which of the two you want rewritten, so here's solutions for both cases

first

```
  location = /abc.html {
            rewrite ^ /hello/$arg_arg1-$arg_arg2 last;
    }
```

second

```
location ~ ^/hello/(\w+)-(\w+) {
    rewrite ^ /abc.html?arg1=$1&$arg2=$2 last;
}
```

Comment: Expected url is www.example.com/hello/x123-555L

Comment: Still not working I have added my conf file is there any issue in that?